# LinuxでParaViewGUIを起動すると文字化けが

Tags: linux, 文字化け

ホスト：MacOSXYosemite
ゲスト：CentOS7.0

で、Virtualboxを使った仮想環境を構築しました。OpenFOAMというオープンソースソフトウェアを仮想CentOS上にinstallして使っています。paraFoamというコマンドを実行するとParaViewというソフトのGUIが起動するのですが、写真のように文字化けしてしてしまいます。

どなたか同じような現象や解決策などはございますか？
回答よろしくお願いします。
[image: 文字化けするParaView]

**追記**

スクリーンショットに映っているワーニングメッセージ

> QFont::SetPointSize: Point size <= 0 (-2), must be greater than 0

Comment: アサーションメッセージを追記しました。ちなみに、Ubuntu Linux 12.04(32bit)版の paraview 4.0.1/Qt 4.8.4 ではこの現象は発生しません。

Comment: heliac2001さんコメントありがとうございます。検索してもなかなか見つからない問題でした。もし解決が難しいようなら、Ubuntuを使う手もありそうですね。